# Importing 3D Analyst functions with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst

This really seems like I should be able to do this, but I am running into some problems. I want to import 3D Analyst with python, in the same way I import Spatial Analyst, but it returns an error.

For Spatial Analyst I use the following:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
```

This allows me to use the spatial analyst functions in python scripts outside of ArcMap. I want to do the same with 3D analyst, but I am running into an error.

I really feel like it should just be:

```
from arcpy.3D import *
```

I also tried arcpy.3d, but either way I get the error:

```
Parsing error <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (line 1)
```

Comment: I know that I can use a 3D Analyst tool with say: arcpy.aspect_3d(), but I am mainly wondering if I can import the 3D Analyst library the same way.

Comment: Spatial Analyst is a module within arcpy which allows the from ___ import * syntax.  3D is not a module so you can't import it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the info @twospeeder I was just starting to think the same thing.

Comment: @twospeeder - You should post that as an official answer so that it is searchable by other people with potentially the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial Analyst is a module within arcpy which allows the from *_* import * syntax. 3D is not a module so you can't import it that way.

Comment: @CodyBrown suggest you unaccept this incorrect answer.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for bumping this old question, but a Python module's name cannot begin with a number, so arcpy.3d will never work. To import the module, you'll need to reference ddd:

```
from arcpy.ddd import *
```

or:

```
from arcpy import ddd
```

A geoprocessing tool can be referenced in arcpy by either arcpy._ or arcpy... For 3D Analyst, the toolbox alias is '3d' but the module name is 'ddd'.

Comment: Thank you for adding an answer that is correct. It's a little sad that a patently, demonstrably false answer was accepted as correct on this question.