# What is the arcpy.ddd module?

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst

I see arcpy.ddd referenced in 3D Analyst code, but I don't see it documented anywhere.  What is this module and how does it relate to 3D Analyst?
For example:

[Stack Profile](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/stack-profile.htm)

```
# Execute StackProfile
arcpy.ddd.StackProfile(profileLine, profileTargets, profileTable, graphName)
# Execute SaveGraph
arcpy.management.SaveGraph(graphName, outGraph)
```

Comment: In addition to @artwork21 answer, if you're asking *why* `ddd` instead of `3d`, my _best guess_ is its generally bad form to start variables, classes, methods, etc with a number. Thus, three letter 'd' = 3d. (best guess as this was created well before I joined esri)

Comment: It looks like a similar answer is here: [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32095/import-3d-analyst-functions-with-arcpy/184175#184175)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type `arcpy.ddd` into the python console in ArcMap or ArcCatalog it notes arcpy.ddd is:

> arcpy.ddd The 3D Analyst toolbox provides a collection of
>   geoprocessing tools that enable a wide variety of analytical, data
>   management, and data conversion operations on surface models and
>   three-dimensional vector data. The toolbox is conveniently organized
>   into toolsets which define the scope of tasks accomplished by the
>   tools therein.

I'm guessing it is a class that holds the related 3D geoprocessing methods.

Comment: Yup, the same as "management" in the code sample, or "na" for network tools.